# Angular Modal, Do I Need to Specify Close Behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), Angular JS demonstrates that for their `$uibModal` you *can* specify what happens on close, i.e.

```
$scope.closeClientModal = function () {
    $scope.clientModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

However, if I remove this, the modal still works. Is this just for the purposes of extensibility demonstration or is it really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to pass arguments to the promise returned when opening a modal so you can execute something when it closes, your modal will still work fine if you don't need anything to happen after it closes.

Comment: I figured that was the case. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't orphaning some instance, somewhere.